# visual studio code error when debugging xunit test

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

> Failed to run test because null.

Strange error attempting to run an xunit test in **visual studio code**.

[image]

Comment: It seems that this error message comes from https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/src/features/dotnetTest.ts#L52
Are you trying to run a .net framework xUnit test? Looks like only dotnet core tests are supported!?

Comment: Hah - the small print - it's a regular dotnet project - do you want to post that as the answer - I'll stick with studio - and it's restarts :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this error message comes from [github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/src/featur‌​es/](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/src/features/dotnetTest.ts#L52) Are you trying to run a .net framework xUnit test? Looks like only dotnet core tests are supported!?

Answer (score 0):

For us the problem was nested classes. OmniSharp cannot handle this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public class SomeMethod
    {
        [Fact]
        public void SomeTest()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

It can however handle this:

```
public class SomeMethod
{
    [Fact]
    public void SomeTest()
    {

    }
}
```